# Check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I create a programme to text data selection on cassandra.
Here is my code.
It's just a simple select all data and show it in the console.

```
def get_spark_context(app_name, max_cores=120):
    # checkpointDirectory = ""
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster(local_settings.SPARK_MASTER).setAppName(app_name) \
        .set("spark.cores.max", max_cores)\
        .set("spark.jars.packages", "datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.0-s_2.11") \
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", local_settings.CASSANDRA_MASTER)

    # setup spark context
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
    sc.setCheckpointDir(local_settings.CHECKPOINT_DIRECTORY)
    return sc

def get_sql_context(sc):
    sqlc = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sc)
    return sqlc

def run():
    sc = get_spark_context("Select data")
    sql_context = get_sql_context(sc)

    sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .options(table="text", keyspace="data") \
        .load().show()
```

However the console show like that. It sticks into the log:

> Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

and it never ends.

```
19/02/21 09:09:22 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/21 09:09:23 WARN Utils: Your hostname, osboxes resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth0)
19/02/21 09:09:23 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/02/21 09:09:44 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
19/02/21 09:09:59 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

Therefore, I have checked my log of spark-worker.
The error log is the following

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/02/21 08:58:18 INFO CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 15264@mm_h01
19/02/21 08:58:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM
19/02/21 08:58:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP
19/02/21 08:58:18 INFO SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT
19/02/21 08:58:19 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/21 08:58:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hadoop,osboxes
19/02/21 08:58:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hadoop,osboxes
19/02/21 08:58:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/02/21 08:58:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/02/21 08:58:19 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(hadoop, osboxes); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(hadoop, osboxes); groups with modify permissions: Set()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1713)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.lookupTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:58)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [120 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    ... 11 more
19/02/21 09:00:19 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask timeout before connecting successfully
```

What does it mean? Is it no commutation between master and workers?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This means that the jobs has been submitted to yarn. However due to insufficient resources it cannot launch the job as  yarn currently can't provide the requested resources.

Go to Ambari/Cloudera UI see if there are any jobs running.
check container size for yarn.
check if the resources configured for the job is more than total available to yarn/mesos

Comment: I don't use Ambari/Cloudera for my base. The hadoop/spark/cassandra are native for my development. Therefore, I have to check spark web ui for the running job?

Comment: use yarn application --list